# as3 file download restrain?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash download on my site to download a pdf file.

```
var myfileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
down_mc.visible = false;
down_comp.visible = false;

var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("GEORGIA INCORPORATED.pdf");
myfileReference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
output_txt.text = "";

function ioError(event:ErrorEvent):void {
output_txt.text = "Sorry that there is an IO error during the file downloading. The error is:" + "\n" + event;

}

myfileReference.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, fileDownloadProgress);

function fileDownloadProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void {

    down_mc.visible = true;
}
myfileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileDownloadCompleted);

function fileDownloadCompleted(evt:Event):void {
    down_mc.visible = false;
    down_comp.visible = true;

}

function downloadFile (event:MouseEvent):void {

    try {
        myfileReference.download(myRequest);
    } catch (error:SecurityError) {

        downloading. The error is:" + "\n" + error; 

    } catch (error:IllegalOperationError) {

        downloading. The error is:" + "\n" + error; 
    }
    }
b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downloadFile);
```

the problem is some people want to change the name of the file they are downloading and changing the extension as well, the .pdf , thus making the file unusable. is there any way to restrain the clients from changing the extension?

Comment: I think you cannot limit users from saving the downloaded file with another extension. It's only a part of the file name, especially when it comes to Linux, and even in Windows it no longer serves crucial purpose, after long names introduction the name+ext are merged into one data field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure as3, you cannot force user to save a file under a specific extention. The only way to do it should be to use Air that let you have control on it through a FileStream Object (you can choose file name).

If you want to do it with Air, then you can do :

```
// Assuming you get your pdf raw data
var pdfData : ByteArray;

var f : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("myPdf.pdf");

// When user have select a file
f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function(e:Event):void{
    var targetFile : File = e.target as File;

    // Check if the selected file have pdf extension
    if(targetFile.nativePath.substr(targetFile.nativePath.length - 4) != ".pdf")
        // If not, add it
        targetFile = new File(targetFile.nativePath + ".pdf");

    // Save the file
    var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(pdfData);
    fs.close();
});

// Ask user to save a file (by default on user desktop)
f.browseForSave("Save PDF");
```

Comment: thanks, The boss decided to let them change whatever they want , it will be their own damn fault if the file doesn't work . thanks though, I'll give it a shot in air :)